# Position div by using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to align a div vertically and horizontaly. The problem is that the div position is not centered. Here's the code I use

```
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>index</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
   window.onload = function(){
   var width = screen.availWidth;
   var height = screen.availHeight;

   var modalWindow = document.getElementById('dialog');

   modalWindow.style.left = (width - modalWindow.offsetWidth) / 2;
   modalWindow.style.top = (height - modalWindow.offsetHeight) / 2;
}
 </script>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
body{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}
div#overlay{
 position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  z-index: 9998;
}

div#overlay #dialog{
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="overlay">
 <div id="dialog">
  <p>some text goes here</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The position of the dialog div is slightly on the right and bottom.
Here is a screenshot
[image]
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using JS to position anything? This could just be done with CSS.

Comment: I know but I want to do it by using js

Comment: If you want to over-complicate things, then ok, but at least provide an example where we can see the issue, because you saying 'slightly right and bottom' isn't technical nor does it say anything about what the issue might be. And your code looks fine, so that doesn't help.

Comment: slime, I've added a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

No need to use Javascript for this. Because your `dialog` element has a set height/width you can do it like this:

```
div#overlay #dialog{
  display:block;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-top:-50px;
  margin-left:-100px;
  background: white;
}
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v0Lq0oe4/)

Comment: Um, no. You did not say that. You said that in a comment AFTER I had already begun this answer. Good luck getting any help with that attitude.

Comment: @MZON, why are you insist on JS when it's so easy in CSS?  Just curious.

Comment: @Steve I'm new to javascript and I do some experiments. Thats the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You're positioning to the corner of the box, and not the center, so you need to take that into consideration when you calculate the position...

```
modalWindow.style.left = ((width - modalWindow.offsetWidth) / 2) - 100 ;
modalWindow.style.top  = ((height - modalWindow.offsetHeight) / 2) - 50;
```

`100` and `50` being half the height and half the width.

Comment: Still not aligned properly

Comment: Did it move at all? And if you look at your image you can clearly see that if the box was moved up and to the left half of it's size then it would be centered. That's what the code should have done, but this is your issue... you need to adjust your position so that is accounted for.